# grunt-contrib-copy: Multiple Copy Tasks

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

Was just wondering if it's possible to set the 'copy' task to do selective copies? Say, if one task wanted to target some files for copying, while another task may want to target others.

I see the 'main' is used in all the examples, but I can't find reference to if other names are able to be used, or another way to accomplish this, outside of using [grunt-multi-dest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-multi-dest)

```js
    copy: {
      main: {
        files: [
          {
            cwd: 'src_static/img/',
            src: ['**'],
            dest: '../mainProject/assets/img/'
          }
        ],
      onlyIcons: {
        files: [
          {
            cwd: 'src_static/img/icons/',
            src: ['**'],
            dest: '../mainProject/assets/img/icons/'
          }
        ],
      }
    }
    grunt.registerTask('copy-all', ['copy']);
    grunt.registerTask('copy-icons', ['copy:onlyIcons']);
```

Although closed, I was asked to reference the question I posted as an issue on the grunt-contrib-copy site: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/230#issuecomment-96467261

Thanks. 
-Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [grunt-multi-dest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-multi-dest) appears to be the clear winner. Even then, there's not much downside to just including and using it. It fills the gap nicely.

Answer (score 15):

For anyone coming across this now, this actually works:

```
grunt.registerTask('copy-all', ['copy']);
grunt.registerTask('copy-icons', ['copy:onlyIcons']);
```

This is going off of KDCinfo's initial Gruntfile config:

```
copy: {
    main: {
        files: [{
            cwd: 'src_static/img/',
            src: ['**'],
            dest: '../mainProject/assets/img/'
        }]
    },
    onlyIcons: {
        files: [{
            cwd: 'src_static/img/icons/',
            src: ['**'],
            dest: '../mainProject/assets/img/icons/'
        }],
    }
}
```

and shows that the `copy.main` and `copy.onlyIcons` must be called as `copy:main` and `copy:onlyIcons` within `grunt.registerTask()`.

Comment: That was hard to find. This should also be the accepted answer, because it works not only with that particular plugin.